# Can the 'View Order' call to action be renamed within Order type?

Tags: gmail, schema.org, google-schemas

I'm using Googles email markup to display a product image and price alongside an image using the 'Order' type. The call to action reads 'View Order'

I would like to rename this call to action link, maybe to read 'Continue' or 'Complete'. Is this possible?

I know in other sections of the schema such as 'Email Message' you are able to change the name of the action, however, they then lack the option to display the product image.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot change the text for the action button for Order markup. As you mentioned it is only possible for few actions like [Go-To action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action) where you can specify the name of the action.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. It turned out if we mixed in an at-type of EmailMessage we were then able to change the call to action text within the at-type of Order by adding in action > name. So it ended up being a schema blend of GoTo and Order.